# Ethernet port not detected

Tags: networking, ethernet, gigabit-ethernet

I just added additional 1gb port to my existing 4gbs on my server. All 4 are placed on a NET CARD `PCIE 1GB E1G44HTBLK 904223 INTEL`
 and the additional one is connected to motherboard(S5520SC) integrated Ethernet port.

from dmidecode I can see the motherboard ports are enabled. but I cannot see the connected port with ifconfig, and nothig in `/var/log/messages`

```
Handle 0x0023, DMI type 10, 6 bytes
On Board Device Information
        Type: Ethernet
        Status: Enabled
        Description: Intel 82575EB

Handle 0x0024, DMI type 10, 6 bytes
On Board Device Information
        Type: Ethernet
        Status: Enabled
        Description: Intel 82575EB
```

ifconfig

```
bond0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:E2:BA:0F:76:B4  
          inet addr:x.x.x.x  Bcast:x.x.x.x  Mask:255.255.255.248
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:356266699619 errors:4899 dropped:528376 overruns:11111 frame:3777
          TX packets:770040754939 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:25080396598186 (22.8 TiB)  TX bytes:1144989523839935 (1.0 PiB)

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:E2:BA:0F:76:B4  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:90733983446 errors:20 dropped:3789 overruns:3788 frame:14
          TX packets:192583010696 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8227697516058 (7.4 TiB)  TX bytes:286322118658675 (260.4 TiB)

eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:E2:BA:0F:76:B4  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:87451584571 errors:2358 dropped:3818 overruns:3817 frame:1765
          TX packets:192424188435 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5575531106457 (5.0 TiB)  TX bytes:286131201457181 (260.2 TiB)

eth4      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:E2:BA:0F:76:B4  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:87860330643 errors:0 dropped:2226 overruns:2225 frame:0
          TX packets:192355678079 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5553458398180 (5.0 TiB)  TX bytes:286034980164619 (260.1 TiB)

eth5      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:E2:BA:0F:76:B4  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:90220801151 errors:2521 dropped:1282 overruns:1281 frame:1998
          TX packets:192677878108 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5723709589219 (5.2 TiB)  TX bytes:286501224120930 (260.5 TiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:8791645789 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8791645789 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:7098296699652 (6.4 TiB)  TX bytes:7098296699652 (6.4 TiB)

ethtool -i eth0
driver: igb
version: 4.0.17
firmware-version: 2.0, 0x2b820001
bus-info: 0000:01:00.0
 ethtool -i eth1
driver: igb
version: 4.0.17
firmware-version: 2.0, 0x2b820001
bus-info: 0000:01:00.1
 ethtool -i eth2
driver: igb
version: 4.0.17
firmware-version: 3.0, 0x619f0001
bus-info: 0000:03:00.0
 ethtool -i eth3
driver: igb
version: 4.0.17
firmware-version: 3.0, 0x619f0001
bus-info: 0000:03:00.1
 ethtool -i eth4
driver: igb
version: 4.0.17
firmware-version: 3.0, 0x619f0001
bus-info: 0000:03:00.2
 ethtool -i eth5
driver: igb
version: 4.0.17
firmware-version: 3.0, 0x619f0001
bus-info: 0000:03:00.3



ethtool  eth0
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: Unknown!
    Duplex: Unknown! (255)
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: off
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
    Link detected: no
 ethtool  eth1
Settings for eth1:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: Unknown!
    Duplex: Unknown! (255)
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: off
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
    Link detected: no
 ethtool  eth2
Settings for eth2:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: off
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
    Link detected: yes
 ethtool  eth3
Settings for eth3:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: on
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: d
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
    Link detected: yes
 ethtool  eth4
Settings for eth4:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: on
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: d
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
    Link detected: yes
 ethtool  eth5
Settings for eth5:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: on
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: d
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
    Link detected: yes
```

Comment: @JiriXichtkniha i have lots of messages like this...`TCP: Peer x.x.x.x:49371/80 unexpectedly shrunk window 3125869243:3125883763 (repaired)` what to grep for?

Comment: First of all is not your card really detected correctly (whole dmesg while booting)? If so, ethool $iface and ethtool -i $iface. You are loosing others' time while not giving as much info as possible.

Comment: I edited my post. please look again. I didn't reboot the system, it's a production.

Comment: Magnificent! You have obscure attitude to not showing us info, why do you have same hwaddr on each iface? Bye!

Answer (score 1):

If this file exists, /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules then remove it. Now create your own /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth6 file. Also make sure that, all the network addresses updated promptly in the respective config files.

Else, you can append your new network device details in this file, /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth5"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not configured bonding? From the above, it seems that you are with bonding enabled. If bonding enabled for interfaces, it wont show any ip's.

Comment: yes it's bonding, but as far as i know it should at least inform you that ethernet cable was plugged in